# Creating a nonogram in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a nonogram puzzle for JavaScript, I'm having a few issues. I am very new to coding so there are things that I have missed and are doing wrong. I'll post my code.

```js
// Nonogram Game

// Hardcoded Levels
let level1 = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

let level2 = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

let level3 = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

// Global Variables
let level1Unsave = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(level1));
let level2Unsave = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(level2));
let level3Unsave = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(level3));
let menu = true;
let returnMenu = false;
let gramComplete = false;
let level1Load = false;
let level2Load = false;
let level3Load = false;
let grid = "menu";
let gridSize = 18;
let cellHeight, cellWidth;
let cellX, cellY;
let nums = [];
let currentLevel;
let buttonWidth = 100;
let buttonHeight = 100;
let returnButtonWidth = 200;
let returnButtonHeight = 100;
let clickSound, misclickSound;
let firstLvl, secondLvl, thirdLvl, returnToMenu, winning;
let state;

// Loading Click Noises
function preload() {
  clickSound = loadSound("assets/Menu Selection Click.wav");
  misclickSound = loadSound("assets/Misclick Sound.wav");
}

function setup() {
  // Creating Grid Perameters
  if (windowWidth < windowHeight) {
    createCanvas(windowWidth*0.8, windowWidth*0.8);
  }
  else {
    createCanvas(windowHeight*0.8, windowHeight*0.8);
  }

  // Giving Variables Values
  state = "starting";
  grid = level1;
  cellWidth = width/gridSize;
  cellHeight = height/gridSize;
  firstLvl = new Button("level1", width/4, height/2, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, color(117, 187, 220), color(137, 207, 240));
  secondLvl = new Button("level2", width/2, height/2, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, color(117, 187, 220), color(137, 207, 240));
  thirdLvl = new Button("level3", width/1.33, height/2, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, color(117, 187, 220), color(137, 207, 240));
  returnToMenu = new Button("backToMenu", width/2, height/2, returnButtonWidth, returnButtonHeight, color(117, 187, 220), color(137, 207, 240));
  winning = new Button("complete", width/2, height/2, returnButtonWidth, returnButtonHeight, color(117, 187, 220), color(137, 207, 240));
}

function draw() {
  // Displaying Menu
  if (menu) {
    background(225); 
    title();
    firstLvl.display();
    secondLvl.display();
    thirdLvl.display();
  }

  // Displaying Grid
  else if (!menu) {
    // Loading the PreClicked Tiles
    if (!level1Load && grid === level1) {
      preClickedBoxes();
      level1Load = true;
    }
    if (!level2Load && grid === level2) {
      preClickedBoxes();
      level2Load = true;
    }
    if (!level3Load && grid === level3) {
      preClickedBoxes();
      level3Load = true;
    }
    
    winCondition();
    lossCondition();
    displayGrid();
    // displayNums();
    
    if (gramComplete) {
      winning.display();
    }

    if (returnMenu) {
      returnToMenu.display();
    }
  }
}

// The Button Class
class Button {
  constructor(level, x, y, butWidth, butHeight, hoverColor, notHoverColor) {
    this.purpose = level;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.butWidth = butWidth;
    this.butHeight = butHeight;
    this.hoverColor = hoverColor;
    this.notHoverColor = notHoverColor;
  }

  // Displaying the Buttons
  display() {
    noStroke();
    if (this.isHover(mouseX, mouseY)) {
      fill(this.hoverColor);
    }
    else {
      fill(this.notHoverColor);
    }
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.butWidth, this.butHeight);
    if (this.purpose === "level1") {
      fill("white");
      textSize(this.butWidth*0.75);
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      text("1", this.x, this.y+7);
    }
    if (this.purpose === "level2") {
      fill("white");
      textSize(this.butWidth*0.75);
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      text("2", this.x, this.y+7);
    }
    if (this.purpose === "level3") {
      fill("white");
      textSize(this.butWidth*0.75);
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      text("3", this.x, this.y+7);
    }
    if (this.purpose === "backToMenu") {
      fill("white");
      textSize(40);
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      text("RETURN", this.x, this.y+5);
    }
    if (this.purpose === "complete") {
      fill("white");
      textSize(40);
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      text("WINNER", this.x, this.y+5);
    }
  }

  // Checking if the Mouse is Hovering Over the Button
  isHover(x, y) {
    return x >= this.x - this.butWidth/2 && x <= this.x + this.butWidth/2 &&
           y >= this.y - this.butHeight/2 && y <= this.y + this.butHeight/2;
  }
}

// Resets the Level When at the Menu Screen (WIP)
function loadLevel() {
  level1 = level1Unsave;
  level2 = level2Unsave;
  level3 = level3Unsave;
}

// Adds the Title to the Menu Screen
function title() {
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill("black");
  text("NONOGRAM", width/2, height/5);
}

// Making the Buttons Work
function mousePressed() {
  // Making Menu Buttons Work
  if (firstLvl.isHover(mouseX, mouseY) && menu) {
    clickSound.play();
    grid = level1;
    menu = false;
  }
  else if (secondLvl.isHover(mouseX, mouseY) && menu) {
    clickSound.play();
    grid = level2;
    menu = false;
  }
  else if (thirdLvl.isHover(mouseX, mouseY) && menu) {
    clickSound.play();
    grid = level3;
    menu = false;
  }
  
  // Making Exit Buttons Work
  if (returnToMenu.isHover(mouseX, mouseY) && returnMenu) {
    clickSound.play();
    grid = "menu";
    menu = true;
    returnMenu = false;
  }

  if (winning.isHover(mouseX, mouseY) && returnMenu) {
    clickSound.play();
    grid = "menu";
    menu = true;
    returnMenu = false;
  }

  // Making the Your Clicks Work
  cellX = Math.floor(mouseX/cellWidth);
  cellY = Math.floor(mouseY/cellHeight);

  if (grid !== "menu") {
    if (grid[cellY][cellX] === 1 && !menu && !returnMenu) {
      clickSound.play();
      grid[cellY][cellX] = 2;
    }
    if (grid[cellY][cellX] === 0 && !menu && !returnMenu) {
      misclickSound.play();
      grid[cellY][cellX] = "X";
    }
  }
}

// Bring up Return Button Mid-Game
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === ESCAPE && !menu && !gramComplete) {
    returnMenu = true;
  }
}

// Displaying the Numbers (WIP)
function displayNums() {
  let count;

  for (let y=0; y<gridSize; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<gridSize; x++) {
      if (grid[y][x] === 1 || grid[y][x] === 2) {
        count++;
      }
      if (count >= 3) {
        returnMenu = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Getting Preclicked Boxes on the Grid
function preClickedBoxes() {
  let count = 0;

  for (let y=0; y<gridSize; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<gridSize; x++) {
      if (grid[y][x] === 0) {
        let raNum = random(100);
    
        if (raNum < 51 && count < 324) {
          grid[y][x] = "XX";
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Displaying the Grid
function displayGrid() {
  // Calling Grid Lines Function
  drawGridLines();

  for (let y=0; y<gridSize; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<gridSize; x++) {
      fill("white");
      strokeWeight(1);
      rectMode(CORNER);
      rect(x*cellWidth, y*cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);

      if (grid[y][x] === 2) {
        fill("black");
        rect(x*cellWidth, y*cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
      }
      else if (grid[y][x] === "X" || grid[y][x] === "XX") {
        fill("black");
        textSize(cellWidth*0.75);
        textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
        text("X", x*cellWidth + cellWidth/2, y*cellHeight + cellHeight/2);
      }
    }
  }
}

// Drawing the Grid Lines
function drawGridLines() {
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke("black");
  for (let location=0; location<gridSize; location++) {
    line(0, cellHeight*location, width, cellHeight*location);
    line(cellWidth*location, 0, cellWidth*location, height);
  }
  line(width, 0, width, height);
  line(0, height, width, height);
}

// Setting Loss Condition
function lossCondition() {
  let count = 0;

  for (let y=0; y<gridSize; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<gridSize; x++) {
      if (grid[y][x] === "X") {
        count++;
      }
      if (count >= 3) {
        returnMenu = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Setting Win Condition
function winCondition() {
  let count = 0;

  for (let y=0; y<gridSize; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<gridSize; x++) {
      if (grid[y][x] === 1) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (count <= 0) {
    returnMenu = true;
  }
}
```

I am currently having two issues:

- It clicks a space when selecting the button to enter a game.
- I don't know how I am going to count the spaces and display them on the side.

I want to fix the button pressing when you enter and want the spaces to put the numbers on the side of the box in line with the column it represents.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different languages. It looks like you're writing about JS but talking about Java. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know they were different, I do mean JavaScript, not Java my apologies.

Comment: That is a lot of code and doesn't seem to be a complete example. It would be hard to help you. I suggest giving us either a working example or a minimal working example that shows the specific problem you are hitting.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, this is all of the code that I have written, and it does work as to my knowledge

Comment: Umm, if this is JavaScript meant to run in a browser, there is apparently something missing because when I click "Run code snippet", nothing happens. Likely because nothing gets called initially; just some variables get initialized.

Comment: yeah I noticed that too, but I dont know why. It does work if you put it in vscode and run it, but not in here

Comment: Code is missing because there is no method `loadSound`, `textAlign`, etc